# Jquery UI Draggable not working with error has no method 'isOver'

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable

My problem is simple but debugging the issue is proving difficult. I'm using jQuery v1.8 with the UI core v1.9.2.

Using "draggable", when I drag an item with my mouse, it doesn't drag at all and I"m giving this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'isOver'
```

The code I have for draggable is:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  cursor: 'move',
  start: function(e, ui) {},
  drag: function(evt,ui) {},
  stop: function(e,ui) {}
});
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: your draggable code looks fine. can you show us the rest of your code ?